# VB.Net OleDb Connecting to Previous Source

Tags: .net, vb.net, connection-string, oledb

I have a simple application that's retrieving data from two different sources using the same OleDb provider. If I click btnSource1 it's supposed to retrieve data from url1 and if I click btnSource2 it's supposed to retrieve data from url2. Each source has a different Data Source, Password, and User ID within the ConnectionString.

The first connection works fine, but any time I switch from one source to the other, the connection fails with an invalid login. Then, if I make a second attempt, that second attempt works fine and queries the correct source. Every time I switch sources, the first attempt fails but all subsequent attempts work.

Debugging shows the correct connection string being used, but it's definitely using the connection from the previous attempt. Am I missing something obvious?

```
Private Sub btnSource1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSource1.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=myprovider;Data Source=url1;Password=password1;User ID=userid1")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) as num from table", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvResults.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSource2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSource2.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=myprovider;Data Source=url2;Password=password2;User ID=userid2")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) as num from table", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvResults.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Per suggestions in the comments, I've reconfigured things to use Using statements. The problem persists.

```
Sub btnSource1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSource1.Click

    Dim cs As String = "Provider=myprovider;Data Source=url1;Password=password1;User ID=userid1"
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) as num from mytable", cn)
            Try
                With cmd
                    .Connection.Open()
                End With
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub btnSource2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSource2.Click

    Dim cs As String = "Provider=myprovider;Data Source=url2;Password=password2;User ID=userid2"
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) as num from mytable", cn)
            Try
                With cmd
                    .Connection.Open()
                End With
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Start a test by declaring all of your objects (except the DataTable) with `Using` statements.  You can remove the `OleDbDataAdapter` here, you're not actually using it, just `Load()` the DataTable with the DataReader.

Comment: "table" is a reserved word. Also, properly dispose of ALL of your objects that have `Dispose` methods. You may consider using `using statements` .

Comment: I've modified the code with Using statements, but the problem persists. "Table" was just an example - I've updated it to mytable for clarity.

Comment: Try to add `pooling=false` to your connection string, see whether that helps. -- Can you specify the Provider? I made a test but could not replicate.

Comment: pooling=false didn't help. Unfortunately the Provider is a custom ADO driver from a vendor I work with. I suppose it's possible that the Provider isn't properly disposing of the connection, but is there any way for me to actually pinpoint that?

Comment: Then try `OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool()` and `GC.Collect()` right after. It's subject to a time-out though. - You could also try to set `Connection Lifetime` (or `Load Balance Timeout`) to a value `> 0` (expresses seconds. `0` = max timeout).

Comment: i suspect you are correct about the issue being in the custom provider. even your initial code would work fine with a sql server provider or a ms access provider. i would email your example to the vendor.

Comment: in your first attempt you had `close` but you had not called `dispose`, hence you started to use `using`. Now, I would add to it an explicit `close` before exiting `using`. I've seen providers having issues. Even `MySql` provider for .net had horrible bug in `close\dispose` -disposing command would kill the connection. and struct like yours wouldn't be working properly... I would also use some disassembler to look inside. `dotPeek` is a tool I use

Comment: You can always do a HACK. Just put this code in a loop. Lets say, you tried 2 times, if it is still failing - exit. But otherwise, have 2 tries.

Comment: Also!!! Execute reader should be wrapped into `using` too

Answer (score 1):

If we could see this a bit closer to the real code, perhaps we could see the error. At any rate, if you are only retrieving the count use `ExecuteScalar`.

You can combine the connection and command in the same Using.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cs As String = "Provider=myprovider;Data Source=url1;Password=password1;User ID=userid1"
    Dim Count As Integer
    Try
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(cs),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) as num from mytable", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Label1.Text = Count.ToString
End Sub
```